# Xamarin Forms Maps Geocoder Not Working on UWP Device

Tags: xamarin.forms

My app uses Xamarin.Forms.Maps to display a map and also for geocoding. The map is displayed on a separate page when the user navigates to it from the main page. I use the geocoder to reverse geocode the current location so that I have the address.  This is done from various places other than the map page.

When I run the app on a device (even in debug mode) the geocoder works right away in iOS and Android, but does not work in UWP. After I navigate to the map page and display the map, then go back to a different page to use the geocoder it starts working.

I saw a thread about the map not working with release build so I added the following code:

```
var laRendererAssemblies = new[] { typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Maps.UWP.MapRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly };
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, laRendererAssemblies);
//Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);
Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init("MyBingMapsKey");
```

This has not helped the issue with the Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Geocoder. I also tried creating an instance of Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map in my main page, but that did not help either. Is there a way to prime the map component so that the Geocoder will work on a device? (My test device is ARM, but it happens when I run on Local 
Machine (Win 10) too)

Following is a snippet of the call to the Geocoder (which works fine once the user has navigated to the Map page and back - and it works fine in iOS and Android - and as such I don't believe it is a problem with the code, but here it is):

```
    public static async Task<Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position> Geocode(string address)
    {
        try
        {
            var loGeocoder = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Geocoder();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Get Lat/Lon");
            var lcolPositions = await loGeocoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync(address);
            if (lcolPositions != null)
```

Comment: Yes, location capability is set.  I actually don't have a problem grabbing the location, it is the Geocoder that isn't working.

Comment: The only other code is accessing the Geocoder.  I thought the init was all that was required but it isn't working.

Comment: Like I said, once the user navigates to the Map Page, it seems to start working, so something in the Init is not setting things up to use the Geocoder.

Comment: Really?  There is no need to be condescending and rude.  The code is in the app.cs.  What code can I show you?  It is a Xamarin Forms app and it works fine in both iOS and Android, it is only UWP that isn't working.  "Like you said", all I should need is the init which I have in the app.cs.

The call to GetPositionsForAddressAsync does not return an error, it just returns nothing.  I've added a snippet my post.

Comment: I've removed my previous comments as not to detract from your OP, however to briefly retort, I was not trying to be rude and or condescending. But when people suggest you post ALL of the relevant code no matter how irrelevant you may feel it, and then arguing the point wastes the time of those who are trying to help you.When you encounter a problem that in theory shouldn't happen, every bit of relevant code can help debug the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research and ensuring that your geodecode class being static wouldn't mess with the async/await pattern in the UWP build. I've come across a few references to this particular problem with the built in Forms.Map geodecoder elsewhere, not just for UWP it has also been noted for android<sup>‡</sup>.

I took some time to have a look at one of our current cross-platform applications that we have in the app stores, and according to our internal documentation we switched out both the xamarin.forms map, and the geodecoder for custom ones.

The plugin that we use for our cross-platform application is the 'GelocatorPlugin' created by james montemagno, and can be found [here.](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin)

It can be added to your project as a Nuget package if you prefer, and the implementation of it is very similar to the default one, so there's very little code to change. The primary benefit is that the UWP element of the geodecode plugin has been modified to take into account windows advanced tracking scenarios ([details found here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2012/12/03/geoposition-advanced-tracking-scenarios-for-windows-phone-8/#K4Gvq2hHdP1y1gXg.97)).

---

It should be a lot more stable than the one your using, once installed you simply use it like so:

> Reverse Geocoding
>
> Based on a location that is passed in, thi swill grab a list of
>   addresses.
>
> UWP requires a Bing Map Key, which you can acquire by reading this
>   [piece of documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/authentication-key).

```
try
{ 
  var addresses = await locator.GetAddressesForPositionAsync (position, string mapKey = null);
  var address = addresses.FirstOrDefault();

  if(address == null)
    Console.WriteLine ("No address found for position.");
  else
    Console.WriteLine ("Addresss: {0} {1} {2}", address.Thoroughfare, address.Locality, address.Country);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Unable to get address: " + ex);
}
```

---

<sup>‡</sup> Links to similar problems - [Link 1](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19708/why-geocoder-getpositionsforaddressasync-returns-no-results), [Link 2](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52725/unable-to-get-geocoding-reverse-geocoding-results-from-android-locations-geocoder)

Comment: Hi Digitalsa1nt, thank you for sticking with it.  I am actually using James's geolocator plugin to grab the current location. James did not have his v4 with the GetAddress...function in production so I am using an older version and relying on xf maps to geocode.  I now see that James has has released v4 so I should look at it.  The doc doesn't mention forward geocoding which I also need to do, but maybe it is there.  I have a Bing Maps key.

Comment: I could also just make REST calls to the Bing Maps API when on UWP, but I would still think Xamarin should make their product do what it is designed to do.

Comment: I'm with you 100 percent on that one, the maps and geodecoder functionality of the forms solution is quite far behind if you ask me. A rest call is certainly an option but it'd be nice to have one decent cross platform solution that works. I definitely think updating it to v4 is a good start. Looking at the github commits for the latest build seems like there's been a decent amount of work done to the UWP part.

Answer (score 0):

> resolved after added following lines in APP.xaml.cs (UWP project)

```
Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init("bingmapkey");
Windows.Services.Maps.MapService.ServiceToken = "bingmapkey";
```